# Setting the text of a UILabel to an int?

Tags: objective-c, text, nsstring, int, uilabel

The question is pretty much self explanatory. I need to set the text property of a UILabel instance to an int. How do I go about doing this? Sorry if it's a nooby question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you have:

```
UILabel *myLabel; //instance of your label
int myInt; //the integer you need to set as text into UILabel
```

you can do this, and it's pretty simple:

```
[myLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myInt]];
```

or:

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myInt];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:yourInt];
[yourLabel setText:[number stringValue]];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",intNumber];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", intValue]];
```